# Cannot found the tables after the migration from SQL server to Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-migration

I have migrated the SQL Server database to Oracle using SQL DEVELOPER, I have followed all steps for the migration:

[image]

The migration passed successfully, but I cannot find the tables in the database.

I only found those tables(auto-generated on any Oracle migration):

[image]

Can the tables be located in another place? how can I find them?

Comment: Try to login with dba and search one of the table in `dba_tables` view. (Uppercase tablename)

Comment: You should have a new schema of the same name as your sql server database, look there under other users

Comment: @Popeye,  nothing is founded after the search.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith, I already check that, but there is nothing.

Comment: there are logs all over the place, did you check those?